# Spring security expression sec:authorize dont work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to show a tag for login to an anonymous user and an a tag for logout tu authenticated user that have ROLE_USER im using the sec:authorize but it doesn't do nothing, dont give me error just dont work.

this is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

if i print the principal i got this:

```
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
```

and for authenticated:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=Balza, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A2C735A0D12E494E89DC72BB9BAD7119], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
```

the thymeleaf page have:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" lang="it">
```

and the sec:authorize is:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"><a class="dropdown-item" href="login">Login</a></li>
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"><a class="dropdown-item" href="perform_logout">Logout</a></li>
```

Security Config:

```
@Override
protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/anonymus*").anonymous() //role anonymus
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll() //resources
            .antMatchers("/addAuthors").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)

            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key("superSecretKey")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(18000) //5 ore
            .tokenRepository(tokenRepository())


            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/perform_logout", "GET"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();
}
```

I tried also this solution but i got Unknown html tag sec:authorize thymeleaf:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyAuthority('ANONYMOUS')"><li><a class="dropdown-item" href="login">Login</a></li></sec:authorize>
```

I also tried to retrive the name of the logged user but dont work, its like i dont have the info of the user that is visiting the page

EDIT:

I used this "workaround" but i dont know if this is a correct approach:

```
<li><a th:if="${role == '[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]'}" class="dropdown-item" href="login">Login</a></li>
<li><a th:if="${role == '[ROLE_USER]'}" class="dropdown-item" href="perform_logout">Logout</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the granted authority is as such `Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]`. A role for spring security would be `ANONYMOUS`.

Update the security tag to

`sec:authorize="hasRole('ANONYMOUS')"`

or you can use

`sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"`.

---

The documentation of `hasRole(String role)` is as below.

> Returns true if the current principal has the specified role.
>
> For example, hasRole('admin')
>
> By default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be
> added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on
> DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

Reference: [Spring security common built-in expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#el-common-built-in)